# Location manager region monitoring

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am using following apple cllocation manager region monitoring methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLCircularRegion *)region
{
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLCircularRegion *)region
{
}
```

the problem is that these method does not get called when application is in suspended state and not running.Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Have you checked the `backgroundRefreshStatus` for your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use significant location change instead of start updating location.Also there is a limit of radius to monitor ,minimum radius should be 100 m

Comment: oh man you have solved my problem , i was banging my head since a month .thanks its working now i forgot to check radius .